# Trouble Installing libsodium on Centos 6

Tags: php, centos6, yum, libsodium

I'm running CENTOS 6.7 and Apache and PHP 5.4.x. I'm using the EPEL and REMI repositories. I'm trying to install the `libsodium` extension.

It is my understanding that I need to install `libsodium` first, then the extension. Based on Googling, to get the right version, I ended on:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php54-php-pecl-libsodium
```

and I get the following result:

```
Installed:
  php54-php-pecl-libsodium.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el6.remi

Dependency Installed:
  audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.3.7-5.el6
  environment-modules.x86_64 0:3.2.10-2.el6
  libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.40.rc1-17.el6_7
  libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.0.94-5.8.el6
  libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.0.43-5.1.el6
  php54-php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.45-7.el6.remi
  php54-runtime.x86_64 0:2.1-4.el6.remi
  policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.0.83-24.el6
  setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.7-4.el6
  setools-libs-python.x86_64 0:3.3.7-4.el6
  tcl.x86_64 1:8.5.7-6.el6
```

Then I type in:

```
pecl install libsodium
```

and I get:

```
[root@core3 tmp]# pecl install libsodium
downloading libsodium-1.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download libsodium-1.0.5.tgz (169,801 bytes)
.....................................done: 169,801 bytes
9 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootAHK93D/libsodium-1.0.5
running: /var/tmp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libsodium support... yes, shared
checking for libsodium files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please install libsodium - See https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium
ERROR: `/var/tmp/libsodium/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

You can see the error seems to indicate that libsodium is not installed when it is. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Have you first done `yum install libsodium-devel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**php54-php-pecl-libsodium** is a SCL package (for parallel installation).

You probably need **php-pecl-libsodium**.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-libsodium
```

You don't need to run the "pecl install comand".

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't need to run the pecl install either. Thank you!

Comment: yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-libsodium

Comment: There's a typo. The d and s are transposed.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've installed a PECL module, but I believe that running the initial command would have taken care of installing the module, no need to run `pecl` manually after that.

Indeed, we can see that the file list from `rpm` shows the module installed along with a `php.ini` file to include it.

```
$ rpm -qlp http://rpms.famillecollet.com/store/php54/php/pecl/libsodium/1.0.5/php54-php-pecl-libsodium-1.0.5-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
/opt/remi/php54/root/etc/php.d/libsodium.ini
/opt/remi/php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/libsodium.so
/opt/remi/php54/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/libsodium
/opt/remi/php54/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/libsodium/LICENSE
/opt/remi/php54/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/libsodium/README.md
/opt/remi/php54/root/var/lib/pear/pkgxml/php54-php-pecl-libsodium.xml
```

Did you make sure to restart your web server?