# Cant successfully set up libsodium extension for PHP on Bluehost CentOS

Tags: php, pecl, libsodium

I have a server on Bluehost running PHP 7.2.15, and I can't get the libsodium extension up and running.

I've tried various tutorials including:

https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/534

I managed to untar the libsodium tarball but i failed when I got the the phpize part, phpize doesnt seem to be installed on the Bluehost machine and attempting to install php-devel with

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-devel
```

i got error:

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-7.2.13-2.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-0.2.0-7.7.1.cpanel.x86_64

I've also tried some stack overflow questions such as

[Trouble Installing libsodium on Centos 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705155/trouble-installing-libsodium-on-centos-6)

But to no avail. With this i fail when i get to the PECL command part, PECL command doesnt seem to exist on the machine although PEAR is installed, which makes no sense to me.

I really need to get libsodium up and running. I added extension=libsodium.so to my php.ini file but libsodium is not appearing in the phpinfo().

If someone can guide me through all of the steps necessary to get libsodium up and running on my server using SSH to the point that i can access libsodium functions in my PHP code, I'm attaching a $20 bounty to achieve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> ea-php-cli-0.2.0-7.7.1.cpanel.x86_64

You are not running CentOS but a cpanel heavily altered distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So are you suggesting that it has to be done a different way? Is there a different way to do it?